# Populate value of input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to populate paragraph using  script below, but how can I populate input field value using this script? Any idea?

```
$(function check(){     
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#forma').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    
        $('.qty').each(function(){ 
           if($(this).val() != '0')
             {
                $('#output').text($('#output').text()+ ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' ' + $(this).val()+ ';' );
             }
          });
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: `$('#someInput').val('some value');` ?

Comment: This script checks all input fields inside form and gets its value and name if value is greater than 0 and shows result in paragraph with output id. I have tried to add same id to the input field, but nothing happens. I am very beginner in javascript so can you explain your answer little bit better. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if all you tried was to change the selector then that won't work.  You can't set the `.text()` of an `input` because it doesn't have a "text" to set.  It has a "value".  It's a subtle semantic difference, but an important one.  So to set the value you would use the `.val()` function.

Comment: Just tried as soon as I saw @fritzi2000 answer and it works. Thank you both of you for great help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is essentially the same as with the paragraph, i.e. you select the element by its id or class. The difference is that for input fields you have to use `.val("someValue")`, whereas for paragraph you have to use `.text("SomeText")` just as you did.

Hope this helps.